# Ruby on Rails implementation similar to Java enums

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

### Details (Flavor Enum)

```java
public enum Flavor {

    SWEET("sugar", 10),
    SOUR("vinegar", 20),


    private final String ingredient;
    private final int price;

    private Flavor(String ingredient, int price) {
        this.ingredient = ingredient;
        this.price = price;
    }


    public String getIngredient() {
        return ingredient;
    }

    public int getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
}
```

Current implementation in ruby code.

```rb
module Drink
  class Flavor
    FLAVORS = {
      sweet: {
        ingredient: 'sugar',
        price: 10,
      },
      sour: {
        ingredient: 'vinegar',
        price: 20,
      }
    }.freeze

    def self.get(flavor)
      APPS[:flavor]
    end
  end
end
```

### Comparison between Java code VS Ruby

The above ruby code works just fine when we only need `ingredient` and `price` attributes but is lacking if I need to fetch the `sweet` or `sour` value. Example of comparison below.

**Using Java enum**

In Java, I can directly use the enum when I need to query for db entries flavored `sweet` or `sour` like below

```java
//in another service
//this will be passed around into different service and/or repositories
//with just this assignment, I have access to the actual enum, the ingredient, and price
Enum flavor = Flavor.SWEET 


//flavor is passed into the repository class
//I can just use the flavor directly to fetch drinks 
drinkRepository.findByFlavor(flavor);
```

**In ruby on rails**

Using the same use-case as the above, this is not possible in ruby.

The below code will not work since `Drink::Flavor.get(:sweet)` will return an object with properties namely `ingredient` and `price`, which is not the value I needed to query from db.

```rb
# in a different class 
# this will be passed around into different class
# this assignment will only provide me ingredient and the price
# WITHOUT the actual `sweet` value
flavor = Drink::Flavor.get(:sweet) 

# in a different service class, I'm aiming to implement the below. 
# this is not working since flavor value is not `sweet` or `sour`
DrinkRepository.find_by(flavor: flavor)
```

### Question:

How can I make the above ruby code work, without adding new field/attribute `flavor` for each object in the hash of FLAVORS in my ruby class?

Answer (score 0):

Calling the constant from the file, you need to pass in the argument and convert it into a symbol.
`:flavor` is not the same as `flavor.to_sym` in your case because if declared as a symbol, it won't have the data passed in the params of `self.get`.

Here's an implementation:

```
module Drink
    class Flavor
        FLAVORS = {
            sweet: {
                ingredient: 'sugar',
                price: 10,
            },
            sour: {
                ingredient: 'vinegar',
                price: 20,
            }
        }.freeze

        def self.get(flavor)
            FLAVORS[flavor.to_sym]
        end
    end
end
```

Then you can call `Drink::Flavor.get(:sweet)` which will yield the JSON for the 'sweet' object. Another good thing about this implementation is you can pass in a symbol or a string `Drink::Flavor.get('sweet')` and it will still work.